# LoadKeyboardLayout doesn't change keyboard layout

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm trying to change the keyboard layout to English, but the changes don't reflect in Windows.

The layout is installed, I have checked with GetKeyboardLayoutList.

[image: screenshot]

**Code:**

```
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    LoadKeyboardLayout("00000409", KLF_ACTIVATE);
    return 0;
}
```

GetKeyboardLayoutName shows that the language has changed, but I don't see that in Windows

**Test code:**

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    TCHAR keyboard[KL_NAMELENGTH];
    GetKeyboardLayoutName(keyboard);
    cout << keyboard << endl;

    LoadKeyboardLayout("00000409", KLF_ACTIVATE);

    GetKeyboardLayoutName(keyboard);
    cout << keyboard << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

**Outputs:**

```
00000405
00000409
[Finished in 2.2s]
```

UPDATE: Tried runnin the .exe on different windows computer, same result

Comment: My crystal ball says that your text editor is not happy about it and switches it back.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/788945/keyboard-layout-randomly-changes-when-i-start-vs-code-or-sublime-text-3

Comment: @HansPassant I don't think it has anything to do with Sublime Text. I tried closing it and running the compiled .exe, same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working with keyboard layout is rather tricky and it is different for Console and GUI applications. And `LoadKeyboardLayout` just make the layout "available" for activation unfortunately.

**GUI**

1. Application **must** have `GetMessage`, `TranslateMessage`, `DispatchMessage` cycle. (Sublime has `GetMessage` cycle)
2. You may switch layout with two sequental calls

   ```
   DWORD dwNewKeybLayout = 0x00000409; // Layout must be already loaded!
   PostMessage(hWnd, WM_INPUTLANGCHANGEREQUEST, 0, (LPARAM)dwNewKeybLayout);
   PostMessage(hWnd, WM_INPUTLANGCHANGE, 0, (LPARAM)dwNewKeybLayout);
   ```

**Console**

Your application with `int main()` is console application, it does not have `GetMessage` cycle. All messages are processed by conhost itself. That's why your `GetKeyboardLayoutName` will not return correct result. Never! No way!

However, you still may change layout *for all processes* are running in this console window. But take in mind, that conhost processes messages asynchronously and the actual layout (which you can't determine or check) may be changed after some lag.

```
    HWND hCon = GetConsoleWindow();
    DWORD dwNewKeybLayout = 0x00000409; // Layout must be already loaded!
    PostMessage(hCon, WM_INPUTLANGCHANGEREQUEST, 0, (LPARAM)dwNewKeybLayout);
    PostMessage(hCon, WM_INPUTLANGCHANGE, 0, (LPARAM)dwNewKeybLayout);
```

Comment: `LPARAM` should be `LoadKeyboardLayout("00000408", KLF_ACTIVATE)` not `"00000408"` I don't think `WM_INPUTLANGCHANGE` does anything (on Windows 10)